# GTK tree view / store column expansion

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, treeview, gtk

I have a treeview packed inside a vbox.

I find that when I resize the window, say expanding it to the right. Then the extra space that is created is only allotted to expanding the last column of the treeview. How do I make this extra space be evenly distributed over all columns of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following on all the `GtkTreeViewColumn`'s that you want to automatically resize:

`gtk_tree_view_column_set_sizing (column, GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_AUTOSIZE);`